# adb install --abi not working in linux emulator

Tags: adb, abi

Wanna run androidTest.apk in `x86` and exec `adb install --abi x86 androidTest.apk`. And started a x86_64 emulator in linux, exec the cmd above, there is output: `can't find 'x86' to install`. I'm sure the APK have x86 so files.

Change `x86` to `armeabi-v7a` also get `can't find 'armeabi-v7a' to install`

Answer (score 0):

Update: Used another way avoid this problem.

`build.gradle` make APK only `x86` abi:

```
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig{
        ndk {
            abiFilters "x86"    
        }
    }
}
```